# Youtube Echo Output is wrong, why?

Tags: php, ip, m3u8

I would like to query the URL  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhgbcmqL7Ck

from the following address via PHP

the download helper outputs the following:

```
https://r3---sn-aigzrn7l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1584745263&ei=z_Z0XsadHc2KgAed-LCICg&ip=89.249.64.220&id=DhgbcmqL7Ck.0&itag=140&source=yt_live_broadcast&requiressl=yes&mh=Ul&mm=44%2C29&mn=sn-aigzrn7l%2Csn-aigl6ner&ms=lva%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=25&gcr=de&initcwndbps=208750&vprv=1&live=1&hang=1&noclen=1&mime=audio%2Fmp4&gir=yes&mt=1584723504&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cgcr%2Cvprv%2Clive%2Chang%2Cnoclen%2Cmime%2Cgir&sig=ADKhkGMwRQIhANSbzljViMgZjCEai4AuAsagRMc068DwAXSXaPhnXfIVAiBYgXZzbfj2x2j-j1f-dlxjkAvPRSsy5ORJ8pmBPKvwZw%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ABSNjpQwRgIhAIy_bOxxUTtpHw9Ul2D3p0Mm6J6sNjqOvizRW7N9qlmuAiEAwk1pcZAFJnJNdm8oyRSDBkY2vi-LkHDNqB4TO-5QKnQ%3D&alr=yes&cpn=G7zpOghYEd58H5bw&cver=2.20200319.09.00&headm=3&rn=2&rbuf=0
```

my php echo

```
https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_variant/expire/1584467557/ei/BbpwXsm3DenczLUP-9us-AY/ip/2a02%3A4780%3Abad%3A20%3Afced%3A1ff%3Afe20%3A51/id/DhgbcmqL7Ck.0/source/yt_live_broadcast/requiressl/yes/tx/23791946/txs/23791272%2C23791946/hfr/1/maudio/1/gcr/us/vprv/1/go/1/keepalive/yes/fexp/23842630/dover/11/itag/0/playlist_type/DVR/sparams/expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Ctx%2Ctxs%2Chfr%2Cmaudio%2Cgcr%2Cvprv%2Cgo%2Citag%2Cplaylist_type/sig/ADKhkGMwRQIgf5bk2T8fVgNntyuhPhRxjeFNkX7mKJ6ves-bc1rcm0ACIQCUaLbgZyLhtJyUjjSMCbqa1gDpfrombbyKx7ENUyiUWQ%3D%3D/file/index.m3u8
```

then I found an m3u8 where the output looks like this

```
https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_playlist/expire/1584741582/ei/buh0XoTCKsG-gAeQ5bXYBQ/ip/78.46.137.84/id/DhgbcmqL7Ck.0/itag/95/source/yt_live_broadcast/requiressl/yes/ratebypass/yes/live/1/goi/160/sgoap/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D140/sgovp/gir%3Dyes%3Bitag%3D136/hls_chunk_host/r3---sn-4g5edne7.googlevideo.com/gcr/de/vprv/1/playlist_type/DVR/initcwndbps/4880/mh/Ul/mm/44/mn/sn-4g5edne7/ms/lva/mv/m/mvi/2/pl/21/dover/11/keepalive/yes/mt/1584719843/sparams/expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,ratebypass,live,goi,sgoap,sgovp,gcr,vprv,playlist_type/sig/AJpPlLswRQIhAPjP2RCQQOqh6uwoWP_S2CBO_butF-ve4W_2lUPeU5K6AiBHLnz4QT43u-CmwJ8GaYI5RUKVCtKB-_LZHzkupZNnDg%3D%3D/lsparams/hls_chunk_host,initcwndbps,mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl/lsig/ALrAebAwRAIgUqP9EGDKS5m8SNOBpKbBGJgJHPURY9eMwhpcCTm3PMoCIFxQrK92mx6b3TtPKCAY-DdBaUiUtTL1vRpIo_M586wL/playlist/index.m3u8
```

So now my question is how do I get the query as in the m3u8?

what am I doing wrong